# Rename an External Module Class Method

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, class, methods

### Question:

How can I rename a method (function) that exists in an imported module class?

General Idea:

```py
#Current Generalized Code
from module import myImportedClass
X = myImportedClass.some_very_long_method_name_that_exists(*args).another_method(*args)

#Becomes Shorter Code
X = myImportedClass.SVLM(*args).AM(*args)
```

### Specific Example:

I have several web-scraping scripts that work, but would like to stylistically rewrite long-lines of code to PEP8 style. One repeated issue that I encounter are verbose method names (especially from the Selenium webdriver module), an imported module class.

Below is an excerpt which conveys what I would like to do. After searching, however, I am unsure exactly how to achieve this end. Would I need to write some sort of local class/function in my Python script that allows the alias to behave like the original method name?

```py
#Current Example with Long Imported Class Method Names
from selenium import webdriver
d = webdriver.Firefox()


def load_job_cards(counter, job_key, job_type, filestem='newjobs'):

    posts = d.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='  row  result clickcard']")
    job_names = [j.find_element_by_css_selector("a[class='turnstileLink']").get_attribute('title') for j in posts]

    #...more code...


#Would Like Imported Class Method to be Renamed, e.g.:
def load_job_cards(counter, job_key, job_type, filestem='newjobs'):

    posts = d.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='  row  result clickcard']")
    job_names = [j.fcss("a[class='turnstileLink']").ga('title') for j in posts]

    #...more code...
```

For reference, the imported WebDriver class methods are documented in the following script:

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/18681a6c1b59434f2639c2c56383a58f1118f009/py/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py

Comment: I have realized additional nuance is needed in the general example (which is perhaps obvious in the specific example). While the very long method name `find_element_by_css_selector(*arg)` is a method of the module `webdriver`, that method needs to work for each element of posts, which itself is a web element from another method executed on `webdriver`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can inherit from `myImportedClass` and define new method:

```
class MyNewClass(myImportedClass):
    def SVLM(self, *args):
        return self.another_method(args)
```

Then you can do

```
from some_module import MyNewClass

MyNewClass(ARGS).SVLM(ARGS2)
```

As per your example, note that `find_element_by_css_selector` is a method of `WebDriver` while `get_attribute` is a method of `WebElement`, so you need to update two classes...

**BUT**! if you really need to make your lines shorter and your code more readable, don't rush to do it. New class and method names might confuse people who will use/maintain your code.

I suggest you just to modify your code as below:

```
post_locator = "xpath", "//div[@class='  row  result clickcard']"
link_locator = "css", "a[class='turnstileLink']"

def load_job_cards(counter, job_key, job_type, filestem='newjobs'):

    posts = d.find_elements(*post_locator)
    job_names = [j.find_element(*link_locator).get_attribute('title') for j in posts]
```

P.S. Note that separating element locators from *executive* code is the basics of PageObject pattern, so it will not be superfluous anyway

Comment: **Thank you!** I had actually never seen this with separating the element locators or `X = type, pattern` and then referencing it with `*X` in the code. That's wonderful.

Answer (score 1):

Building off of @Ashish Kamble's suggestion of functional pointer's, I found a few solutions for my specific case. I still have not figured out how to rename functions to inherit the original class.method's attributes upon the existing web-elements, e.g. `j.fcss("a[class='turnstileLink']").ga('title')`.

Solving the original problem with another function, however, I get:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
d = webdriver.Firefox()


def find_css(element, css):
    return element.find_element_by_css_selector(css)


def load_job_cards(counter, job_key, job_type, filestem='newjobs'):

    posts = d.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='  row  result clickcard']")

    #Breaking the Long Line with the New Function
    css = "a[class='turnstileLink']"
    job_names = [find_css(j, css).get_attribute('title') for j in posts]


    #Other Code Where This is Also Useful
    companies = [find_css(c, "span[class='company']").text for c in posts]
    locations = [find_css(l, "span[class='location']").text for l in posts]

job_names = [slvm2(j, css, ga) for j in posts]
```

```py
#Alt Solution 1
def find_css(element, css):
    return element.find_element_by_css_selector(css)


def ga(element, attribute):
    return element.get_attribute(attribute)


def load_job_cards(counter, job_key, job_type, filestem='newjobs'):

    posts = d.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='  row  result clickcard']")

    css = "a[class='turnstileLink']"
    job_names = [ga(find_css(j, css), 'title') for j in posts]



#Alt Solution 2 (Less Generalizable)
def SVLM(j, css, ga):
    return j.find_element_by_css_selector(css).get_attribute(ga)


def load_job_cards(counter, job_key, job_type, filestem='newjobs'):

    posts = d.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='  row  result clickcard']")

    css = "a[class='turnstileLink']"
    job_names = [SVLM(j, css, 'title') for j in posts]
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont know how to rename but just a little trick can work here using functional pointers,
store full function in variable, then call new function.

```
newFunName =  Package.Module.Function 
newFunName()
```

i hope this will help you

```
from module import myImportedClass
def do(ar) myImportedClass.some_very_long_method_name_that_exists(ar).another_method(ar)
```

Becomes Shorter Code calling like this

```
X = do(**args)
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea of functional pointers. I had to modify your example some to get it to work with my code (example above).